# How to push array values via php function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an empty array that I am trying to push a value to via a simple php function.  The problem is that within each iteration the values are not being retained.  Here is an example:

```
function addColors($arrayValues, $arrayToUpdate){
    $arrayToUpdate[]=$arrayValues;
}

$colors = array();
$newColors= array("red", "blue", "yellow");

foreach($newColors as $newColor){
    addColors($newColor, $colors);
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($colors, true)."</pre>";
```

This will just print an empty array.  Whereas what I would like to see are the values being added to the `$colors` array.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Add **&** to `$arrayToUpdate` and `$newColor` in function definitions to keep it as reference.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but perhaps you just need to pass the array by reference? `function addColors($arrayValues, &$arrayToUpdate){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to return the new array and assign the returned array in the loop:

```
function addColors($arrayValues, $arrayToUpdate){
    $arrayToUpdate[]=$arrayValues;
    return $arrayToUpdate;
}

foreach($newColors as $newColor){
    $colors = addColors($newColor, $colors);
}
```

Or to do it the way you have it, pass the variable that needs to be updated as a reference; notice the `&`.  This is my recommendation:

```
function addColors($arrayValues, &$arrayToUpdate){
    $arrayToUpdate[]=$arrayValues;
}

foreach($newColors as $newColor){
    addColors($newColor, $colors);
}
```

Though in this simple example I wouldn't use a function:

```
foreach($newColors as $newColor){
    $colors[] = $newColor;
}
```

Also, there is already a function that does this, though the arguments are in a different order:

```
array_push($colors, $newColor);
```

Even simpler without the loop:

```
$colors = array_merge($colors, $newColors);
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, I'll award in 11 mins.